# How to calculate the number of videos an Android device can displays at the same time?

Tags: android, react-native, exoplayer, react-native-video

I'm making an app on Android that allow to render and play multiple videos at the same time. The problem is, if there is too much videos, they may start dropping fps, as well as app can be crash or becomes not responding. The current approach is that app will render number or number-1 videos. Therefore, I need to calculate or estimate the number of videos that the device can handle.

I tried to build different apps with React Native (react-native-video) and Native Android (VideoView and ExoPlayer) to see the differences. Not much! Therefore, I assume the number depends on size of videos and how powerful the hardware is.

Does anyone know the answer for this? How can I estimate the number of videos that an Android device can render at the same time, if I already know everything about the videos and the hardware?